# How do I change the default state label for a country on the WooCommerce checkout page?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to modify the WooCommerce checkout page. I want to change the default state label for the UK.

The UK default state label is "county". I want to modify this to "State Code".

I tried the following code but nothing changes.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

  unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
  unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
  $fields['billing']['billing_state'] = array(

  'label'=> __('State Code', 'woocommerce'),
  'required'  => true,
  'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),

  );

 return $fields;
}
```

Comment: try this code http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/120767/90674

Answer (score 0):

My reply might be late but,

Ive had a similar issue earlier so i used the `woocommerce_default_address_fields` instead.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' ,'customize_checkout_fields' );
function customize_checkout_fields( $address_fields ) {

// Customizing city and state labels
$address_fields['city']['label'] = __('Just a City');
$address_fields['state']['label'] = __('Just a State');

return $address_fields;

}
```

Hope this works.

Comment: does not work for US. JS updates these labels. Trying to find where is it.